# Call a variable from [pallet::call] in another pallet

Tags: polkadot, rust

I have declared a variable in `balances/lib.rs` inside a `[pallet::call]` function.

I want to call that variable at runtime in the **staking pallet** after the era completes.

Or is there a way to call the completion of an era in the **balances pallet**?

I am happy with either solution.

Answer (score 1):

To define any variable you should use `pallet::storage` and declare it in `Config` and for accessing that from another pallet you need to use one of two methods that describes in `Pallet Coupling`